# Pandas how to filter dataframe with certain range of numbers in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to come up with a way to filter dataframe so that it contains only certain range of numbers that is needed for further processing.
Below is an example dataframe

```
data_sample = [['part1', 234], ['part2', 224], ['part3', 214],['part4', 114],['part5', 1111],
                ['part6',1067],['part7',1034],['part8',1457],['part9', 789],['part10',1367],
                ['part11',467],['part12',367]
        ]
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_sample, columns = ['partname', 'sbin'])
data_df['sbin'] = pd.to_numeric(data_df['sbin'], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')
```

With the above dataframe i want to filter such that any part with sbin in range [200-230] and [1000-1150] and [350-370] and [100-130] are removed.

I have a bigger dataframe with lot more ranges to be removed and hence need a faster way than using below command

```
data_df.loc[~( ((data_df.sbin >=200) & (data_df.sbin <= 230)) | ((data_df.sbin >=100) & (data_df.sbin <= 130)) | ((data_df.sbin >=350) & (data_df.sbin <= 370))| ((data_df.sbin >=1000) & (data_df.sbin <= 1150)))]
```

that produces output as below

```
    partname    sbin
0   part1       234
7   part8       1457
8   part9       789
9   part10      1367
10  part11      467
```

The above method requires lot of conditions and takes a long time, i would like to know if there is a better way using regex or some other python way that i am not aware off.

any help would be great

Comment: In terms of optimization, if you have more exclusion conditions than inclusion conditions you might be able to do an inclusive mask instead of an exclusive one depending on the data. As an aside, while [Series.between](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) is not faster than individual `and`ed comparisons since is just that in the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.3/pandas/core/series.py#L5098-L5127), it could simplify the syntax a bit to be more legible.

Comment: You'd have to check, but possibly using `pd.cut` could be helpful here to cut the data into bins then select only the bins you want

Comment: `sbin` could be float or only int?

Comment: sbin is going to be definetly int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New version**

Use `np.logical_and` and `any` to select values in ranges and invert the mask to keep other ones.

```
intervals = [(100, 130), (200, 230), (350, 370), (1000, 1150)]
m = np.any([np.logical_and(data_df['sbin'] >= l, data_df['sbin'] <= u)
                                    for l, u in intervals], axis=0)
out = data_df.loc[~m]
```

Note `any` can be replaced by `np.logical_or.reduce`:

```
intervals = [(100, 130), (200, 230), (350, 370), (1000, 1150)]
m = np.logical_or.reduce([np.logical_and(data_df['sbin'] >= l, data_df['sbin'] <= u)
                                    for l, u in intervals])
out = data_df.loc[~m]
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
   partname  sbin
0     part1   234
7     part8  1457
8     part9   789
9    part10  1367
10   part11   467
```

---

**Old version**

*Not work with float numbers as is*

Use `np.where` and `in1d`:

```
intervals = [(100, 130), (200, 230), (350, 370), (1000, 1150)]
m = np.hstack([np.arange(l, u+1) for l, u in intervals])
out = data_df.loc[~np.in1d(data_df['sbin'], m)]
```

---

**Performance**: for 100k records:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'sbin': np.random.randint(0, 2000, 100000)})

def exclude_range_danimesejo():
    intervals = sorted([(200, 230), (1000, 1150), (350, 370), (100, 130)])
    intervals = np.array(intervals).flatten()
    mask = (np.searchsorted(intervals, data_df['sbin']) % 2 == 0) & ~np.in1d(data_df['sbin'], intervals[::2])
    return data_df.loc[mask]

def exclude_range_sammywemmy():
    intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(200, 230), (1000, 1150), (350, 370), (100, 130)])
    return data_df.loc[pd.cut(data_df.sbin, intervals, include_lowest=True).isna()]

def exclude_range_corralien():
    intervals = [(100, 130), (200, 230), (350, 370), (1000, 1150)]
    m = np.hstack([np.arange(l, u+1) for l, u in intervals])
    return data_df.loc[~np.in1d(data_df['sbin'], m)]

def exclude_range_corralien2():
    intervals = [(100, 130), (200, 230), (350, 370), (1000, 1150)]
    m = np.any([np.logical_and(data_df['sbin'] >= l, data_df['sbin'] <= u)
                                        for l, u in intervals], axis=0)
    return data_df.loc[~m]
```

```
>>> %timeit exclude_range_danimesejo()
2.66 ms ± 18.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit exclude_range_sammywemmy()
63.6 ms ± 549 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit exclude_range_corralien()
6.87 ms ± 58.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit exclude_range_corralien2()
2.26 ms ± 8.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @NandeepDevendra, can you check my answer too, please?

Comment: Hi @corralien, yes i will definetly check yours too.

Comment: @DaniMesejo. Your solution is faster than mine but you have a little bug to fix with left interval

Comment: Thanks for putting together the benchmark. I first deleted my answer because was not matching yours, but is matching the one by @sammywemmy. Which to me seems to be correct.

Comment: @DaniMesejo. I fixed my solutions. I removed `np.where` because `np.any` already give me a mask. Now `logical_and` is faster than `np.searchsorted`

Comment: @NandeepDevendra. All answers was updated and benchmarked. Now you can choose :)

Comment: thanks @Corralien , both yours and danimesejo solutions are good and finish in about ms of each other even for my big dataframe with more combinations. Is there a way to accept 2 answers?

Comment: @NandeepDevendra Accepting this one is the right call

Answer (score 5):

`pd.cut` works fine here, especially as your intervals are not overlapping:

```py
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(200, 230), (1000, 1150), (350, 370), (100, 130)])

# if the values do not fall within the intervals, it is a null
# hence the isna check to keep only the null matches
# thanks to @corralien for the include_lowest=True suggestion

data_df.loc[pd.cut(data_df.sbin, intervals, include_lowest=True).isna()]

   partname  sbin
0     part1   234
7     part8  1457
8     part9   789
9    part10  1367
10   part11   467
```

Comment: Seems about twice as fast as OPs approach on the provided sample. Nice :)

Comment: `pd.cut` is efficient for range searching; just a bit murky when intervals overlap

Comment: You may want to test out on some larger samples though because sometimes those functions don't scale as well as a pure numpy or python solution would.

Comment: thanks, will try this out with more conditions on the large dataframe i have and if working will accept the answer @sammywemmy.

Comment: @sammywemmy. I think you have to include `include_lowest=True`. If you append 200 to `data_df`, it will not be excluded.

Comment: @NandeepDevendra, have a look at the numpy based solutions; they certainly offer more performance

Answer (score 2):

For *non-overlapping intervals*, you could use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
# sort the non overlapping intervals
intervals = sorted([(200, 230), (1000, 1150), (350, 370), (100, 130)])

# flatten
intervals = np.array(intervals).flatten()

# search in the intervals, if the index is even is not in the intervals
mask = (np.searchsorted(intervals, data_df['sbin']) % 2 == 0) & ~np.in1d(data_df['sbin'], intervals[::2])

print(data_df.loc[mask])
```

**Output**

```
   partname  sbin
0     part1   234
7     part8  1457
8     part9   789
9    part10  1367
10   part11   467
```

**Timings** *(on a 3,1 GHz Intel Core i7)*

```
%timeit exclude_range_danimesejo()
3.45 ms ± 13.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Setup** *(in addition to the one by @Corralien)*

```
def exclude_range_danimesejo():
    intervals = sorted([(200, 230), (1000, 1150), (350, 370), (100, 130)])
    intervals = np.array(intervals).flatten()
    mask = (np.searchsorted(intervals, data_df['sbin']) % 2 == 0) & ~np.in1d(data_df['sbin'], intervals[::2])
    return data_df.loc[mask]
```

The overall complexity of this approach is `O((n + m) log n)` where `n` is the size of the list of intervals and `m` the length of the `sbin` column.

Comment: the solution seems to miss sbin 200, if present while it does not miss 230? can you check?

Comment: @NandeepDevendra Updated the answer. Could you check?

Comment: I checked and it works now @Dani Mesejo

Answer (score 0):

What about using a loop to apply your interval conditions?

```py
# this will be broadcast to a boolean array where it is `True` if sbin
# is in any of the intervals in the list and `False` otherwise
is_in_intervals = False
intervals = [(200, 230), (1000, 1150), (350, 370), (100, 130)]

for interval in intervals:
    is_in_intervals |= (data_df.sbin >= interval[0]) & (data_df.sbin <= interval[1])

data_df[~is_in_intervals]
```

Comment: This simplifies the mask construction but is it faster than the long form?

Comment: @HenryEcker no, not faster. probably a tiny bit slower due to the loop overhead. although i would presume the masking is pretty fast if it is handled by numpy.

Comment: The question seems to be looking to improve the speed of the computation as supported by "I have a bigger dataframe with lot more ranges to be removed and hence need a faster way than using below command" and "The above method requires lot of conditions and takes a long time, i would like to know if there is a better way"